# Should I close mySQL connection in-between method calls?

Tags: mysql, database

So this question is a matter of good idea/bad idea. I am using a MySQL connection many times in a short amount of time. I have created my own method calls to update values, insert, delete, etc.

I am reusing the same connection for each of these methods, but I am opening and closing the connection at each call. The problem being that I need to check to make sure that the connection is not open before I try to open it again.

So, the question is: Is there danger in just leaving the MySQL connection open in between method calls? I'd like to just leave it open and possibly improve speed while I am at it.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: No. The only time you'd ever need to close a connection is when you **KNOW** you're done using it. Generally a script should open only ONE connection, then use it throughout the lifetime of that script. That being said, there may be cases where you'd want to start with a known good/clean connection, and you MAY want to close in those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, no you shouldn't be closing it if in the same class / library / code scope you're just going to open it again.

This is dependant on the tolling / connection library you're using.  if you're using connection pooling some library's will not actually close the connection (immediately) but return it to the pool.

The only comment I'll make about reusing a connection is that if you're using variables that are connection specific those variables will still be valid for the same connection and may cause problems later if another query uses one of them and it has a value from a past query that is no longer reliant - however this would also raise questions about the suitability of the variable in the first place.

Opening a connection is something is within MySQL is fairly light (compared with other databases) however you shouldn't be creating extra work if you can avoid it.